# How to record and replay control movement in WPF?

Tags: wpf, animation, move

The question is that, e.g. I have a rectangle on the canvas, and I drag it with mouse (since in a physics engine, so both position and orientation will change). I want to record the movement of the rectangle as sth. like ControlAction or what else, and I have a replay button on the canvas, when I hit it, I can choose the corresponding ControlAction to replay the movement.

How can I do above work? Thank you in advance.